# Multiple Row Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where I join a table to another table that stores email addresses. So a query may go:

```
SELECT RT.name, RT.address, ET.email
FROM Reference_Table as RT
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Email_Table as ET ON RT.field = ET.field
WHERE ...
```

However more than one email address can be stored per individual, which can give me this output:

```
Name            Address                       Email
John Smith    1, The Street               js@x.com
John Smith    1, The Street               js1@y.com
```

My desired output would be:

```
Name            Address                       Email 1         Email 2
John Smith    1, The Street               js@x.com       js1@y.com
```

eg having everything on one row, not two rows.

Please can you advise the simplest way of achieving this (if it is simple)?

I've tried one or two things before - which work when there's just one table - but haven't been able to get to a simplish way of resolving the above. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone have 3 email address? Or 4, 5, ..., 10? Or are they limited to 2? If not, what is the most than *can* have.

Comment: Good question, apologies. There is an instance of one record with 17 email addresses(!); most have three maximum however and I would be perfectly content to restrict this to the first two that appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If limiting the e-mail addresses to a fixed number is OK for you, you could use a CTE in which you assign numbers to each e-mail address per name/address using `row_number()` and then join it including the number in the `ON` condition.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT et.email,
       et.field,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY et.field
                          ORDER BY et.email) rn
       FROM email_table et
)
SELECT rt.name,
       rt.address,
       cte1.email email1,
       cte2.email email2
       FROM reference_table rt
            LEFT JOIN cte cte1
                      ON cte1.field = rt.field
                         AND cte1.rn = 1
            LEFT JOIN cte cte2
                      ON cte2.field = rt.field
                         AND cte2.rn = 2
       WHERE ...;
```

If there's another column in `email_table` that defines the order of the e-mail addresses you might want to use that column for the `ORDER BY` clause of the `OVER` clause. Change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems that you have an unknown number of email address, and as such an unknown number of required columns, you'll have to use dynamic SQLt to Pivot this:

```
DECLARE @Max int;

SET @Max = (SELECT MAX(C) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM dbo.Email_Table ET GROUP BY IDColumn));

--SET @Max = 17;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(@Max) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2)
SELECT @SQL = N'WITH Emails AS(' + @CRLF + 
              N'    SELECT RT.[name],' + @CRLF +
              N'           RT.[Address],' + @CRLF +
              N'           ET.Email,' + @CRLF +
              N'           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RT.IDColumn ORDER BY ET.IDColumn) AS RN' + @CRLF +
              N'    FROM dbo.Reference_Table RT' + @CRLF +
              N'         LEFT JOIN dbo.Email_Table ET ON RT.field = ET.field' + @CRLF +
              N'    WHERE ...)' + @CRLF +
              N'SELECT E.[Name],' + @CRLF +
              N'       E.[Address],' + @CRLF +
              STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                            N'       MAX(' + CONCAT(N'CASE E.RN WHEN ',T.I,N' THEN E.Email END') + N') AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'Email',T.I))
                     FROM Tally T
                     ORDER BY T.I
                     FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
              N'FROM Emails E' + @CRLF +
              N'GROUP BY E.[Name]' + @CRLF +
              N'         E.[Address];';

--PRINT @SQL; Your best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

*Note, this is untested, due to the tiny amount of sample data we have, but other than the "`WHERE ...`", the SQL generated above is valid.*